# Make a div extend all the way down on my page?

Tags: css, responsive-design, position, grid-layout, portfolio

This is my page: http://goodshitdesign.no/
(It is a portfolio for my hobby of designing logos)

I simply want to split the page in two under my header, with a box of information on the left and a flexible grid of logos on the right.

The problem is that when I add too many logos the page becomes longer than the 100% it originally is, and the infobox is cut short at the bottom, and logos start appearing under it. You can probably see what I mean on the page.

I cant make the position of the infobox absolute, because then the logos go behind the infobox.

I cant put the logogrid inside its own div, because then the rows and columns wont adjust to what suits the size of the page best.

Can someone please help me? It would be enormously appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using flex-box? `.infobox` and `<center>` should be in a container together. The container can use `display: flex` and `.infobox` and `<center>` can use `flex: grow | shrink | basis | etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flexbox as mentioned, or new css for containers like this:

```
div.infobox {
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #ebebeb;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

for your logo container div:

```
div.logobox {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #d2d2d2;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
display: block;
float: left;    
}
```

parent div:

```
.parentdiv {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%; }
```

logo divs:

```
div.logo {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
width: 200px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.1s ease;
transition: all 0.1s ease; }
```

To change the height of .infobox when the resizing happens, add this javascript in your page in a script tag:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).on("resize",function() {

      var bodyheight = $(document).height();

      $(".parentdiv").height(bodyheight);
 });});
```

Comment: That didnt work at all, this was kinda what I mentioned with "I cant put the logogrid inside its own div, because then the rows and collums wont adjust to what suits the size of the page best." If you refresh my page now you can see what I mean. The rows become fixed with 5 logos each, and if that is too wide it goes under the infobox again

Comment: I see what you're saying now with the logos.. I would need to see what your css is doing to change their size when the browser resizes

Comment: I've been playing with your base css, I'm guessing you want to make this entire page "responsive".  So, you may want to look in to Flexbox or Bootstrap css to do so easily.  The problem is that we can set these containers beside each other, give them percentage widths, absolute positioning as well, but none of that will control your logo divs inside the right side, you need more logic for that

Comment: Right, I agree. Isnt there some way I can make the logos stack flexibly inside the div like they do if there is no div around it at all?

Comment: ok, I was able to get them to stay, and double stack when I combined the css edited in my answer.  This should handle tablet sized screens.  I removed the min-width on the infobox and logo divs, and various other changes

Comment: I just checked your page, looks like you handled it!

Comment: Damn, that looks great! That way the icons stack just how I want them to. Thanks a lot! The only thing missing though is for the background-color of the infobox to go all the way down?

Comment: Function does not seem to work or I may be adding it incorrectly?

Comment: I looked at your page, you need to  reference the latest jquery.  Download it, put it in a script directory, and reference it on your page.  Also, I'm editing it , do it with parentdiv, not .infobox

Comment: Tried that, still wont work. If you check the source code you can see that I have tried all kinds of different ways of adding jquery

Comment: If you open it in Chrome, then hit F12, select "elements', you can see your page and any errors.. the error I'm seeing is that you aren't using the correct path to the jquery you have added.  check your src="" attribute, the path isn't correct.

Comment: Or rather, the script appears to be malfunctioning, making the infobox longer every single time the window is resized, but not when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try changing as below

```
.infobox {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 350px;
   /*additional*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.logobox {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    float: right;/*left to right*/
}
```

hope this help

Comment: What you really need is more html and css for the logo divs dependant on screen width

Comment: i have modified the css. try adding below with existing code as below. when screen get reduced you need to reduce the font size using media queries in oder to make it responsive      div.parentdiv {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative; /*remove height 100%*/
 }
 div.infobox {
   position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0px; /*remove min-width*/
 }
 @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    div.pointslist ul li {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
 input[type="submit"] {
   width: 190px;
   height: 42px;
   font-size: 15px;
 }
  }